# replacing a specific pattern of characters with a particular character in unix shell script

Tags: shell, unix, awk, grep, tr

In starting we need to check if there are 2 or 3 characters before hyphen then that should remain as its and if 
the characters before hyphen(if any) is 1 or more than 3 then we beed to put space after hyphen

input

```
SB-743921- 11C

SBDF-559448-AAA

SBI-742457-A

S-SANJAY PFF

GH222016/Love
```

output

```
SB-743921- 11C

SBDF- 559448-AAA

SBI-742457-A

S- SANJAY PFF

GH222016/Love
```

I am trying it using tr command like

```
cat input.txt|tr "...?-" " "
```

but it is replacing all - by space

Comment: First line of input is `SB-743921- 11C` and in output it is `SB-743921- 14C`, I mean `11C` to `14C`

Comment: its just a typo mistake ......

Comment: `tr` translates one character to another, not one string to another. You need `sed` or `awk`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
awk -F- -v OFS="-" '{for(i=NF-1;i>=1;i--){l=length($i);if(l<2||l>3)$(i+1)=" "$(i+1)}}7' file
```

the above line apply your rule for **every** `-`: for example:

```
kent$  cat f
SB-743921- 11C
SBDF-559448-AAA
SBI-742457-A
S-SANJAY PFF
GH222016/Love

kent$  awk -F- -v OFS="-" '{for(i=NF-1;i>=1;i--){l=length($i);if(l<2||l>3)$(i+1)=" "$(i+1)}}7' f
SB-743921-  11C
SBDF- 559448- AAA
SBI-742457- A
S- SANJAY PFF
GH222016/Love
```

if you just want to check the column before the first `-`, it would be much easier.

### only apply on the first case:

```
 awk -F- -v OFS="-" 'NF>1{l=length($1);if(l<2||l>3)$2=" "$2}7' file
```

Comment: I am getting this o/p

SB-743921-  11C

SBDF- 559448- AAA

SBI-742457- A

S- SANJAY PFF

GH222016/Love

it means its replacing the other hypens also in the same row with space

Comment: @rohit123456 in comment text lost its format, so I cannot see the problem. also I add the input/output example in my answer. check if it is what you want.

Comment: yes i want to check only before the first -

Comment: @rohit123456 see update in answer

Comment: @rohit123456 Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please consider accepting this answer if it helped. You can do so by clicking on the tick mark next to the answer. You can read more about it [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 0):

`tr` **tr** ansliterates one character to another.  You may need to reach into a tool with a more robust regex engine:

```
perl -pe 's/-/- /g; s/- (\w\w\w?)\b/-$1/g;' <input.txt
```

This will put a space in *everywhere* after a hyphen, then remove it in the cases you don't want.

Answer (score 0):

`sed` might be easiest in this case:

```
sed -E 's/^([^-]|[^-]{4,})-/\1- /' input.txt
```

The overall effect is that a space is inserted after the first `-` on lines that do not have either exactly 2 or 3 characters before the first `-`.

- `sed` uses *regular expressions* to match input lines; `-E` (alias in GNU `sed`: `-r`) makes `sed` support *extended* regular expressions (instead of the default *basic* ones), which is always advisable - extended regexes behave much more like regexes in other programming languages - note, however, that extended regexes are NOT part of POSIX, so some platforms may not support them.
- `s/<to replace>/<with what>/` is the `sed` text-substitution (text-replacement) command.
- The initial `^` ensures that matching starts at the *beginning* of each line.
- `[^-]` means: any character *except* a `-`.
- `[^-]|[^-]{4,}` means: match *either* a *single* character other than `-` *or* (`|`) *four or more* characters other than a `-`
- The `(...)`, a so-called *capture group*, causes the string that matches the enclosed expression to be saved (captured) for later use.
- The replacement string references the captured string as `\1` (a so-called *backreference*, here referring to the *1st* (and only) capture group). Using `\1-`  as the replacement string effectively puts a space after the first `-`.
- Any non-matching lines are passed through unmodified (this is `sed`'s default behavior - it prints *all* input lines, whether modified or not).

Comment: This answer turned up in the low quality review queue, presumably because you didn't explain some of the contents. If you do explain this (in your answer), you are far more likely to get more upvotes—and the questioner actually learns something!

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHat Thanks for the hint, I appreciate it. Explanation added.